# Magento 2 | is it possible to set block class by referencing a block?

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, reference

I'm currently rewriting a layout file:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals>

<!-- some stuff -->
</referenceBlock>
```

Is it possible to set the block class here?

Comment: Means you  want to change existing   block class name?

Comment: Yes, I want the block to use another class.

Comment: You do not change the block class name  like a template`(.phtml)` changes

Comment: So it is not possible at all ?

Comment: You cannot change block name using layout

Comment: which block class you want to changes with which class?

Comment: From the xml you could create a new container on the node above checkout.cart.totals, set a class to the container and move the checkout.cart.totals block to that container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2.2.* the short answer: **No**

What you can do instead is to remove and then add new block with your specific class:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <!-- Remove old block -->
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Add new block -->
    <block name="checkout.cart.totals" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Cart\Totals">
        <!-- some stuff -->
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

The other way is to extend Vendor Block class for your needs, you can read more about it here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/module-development.html